# How to make c# don't call destructor of a instance

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two forms and `form1` needs to get data from `form2`, i use a parameter in `form2` constructor to gets `form1's` instance like this:

```
public form2(Form form1) {
this.f = form1;
}
```

and in form1:

```
Form form2 = new Form(this);
```

But it seem form1 destruct was called when i closed form1. my question is how can i avoid this problem?

**EDIT:** I have many typing mistakes in my question, i'm so sorry, fixed:

I have two forms and `form2` needs to get data from `form1`, i use a parameter in `form1` constructor to gets `form1's` instance like this:

```
private Form f;
public form2(Form form1) {
this.f = form1;
}
```

and in form1:

```
Form form2 = new Form(this);
```

But it seem form1 destructor was called when i closed form2. my question is how can i avoid this problem?

Comment: Your topic is very misleading.

Comment: C# doesn't have deterministic destructors, so I'm thinking you mean it's calling `Dispose()` and you're getting an `ObjectDisposedException` can you confirm this?

Comment: Can't you use the Hide function to keep it alive but invisible?

Comment: My mistake, i'm so sorry, i have fixed :-(.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx):

> When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are
>   closed and the form is disposed. You can prevent the closing of a form
>   at run time by handling the Closing event and setting the Cancel
>   property of the CancelEventArgs passed as a parameter to your event
>   handler.

As such, to prevent disposal of the resources, the only thing you can do is hide the form instead of closing it:

```
bool reallyClose;

protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!reallyClose)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        Hide();
    }
    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

This will prevent the form being closed unless you manually set the `reallyClose` flag to `true` before closing the form.

You should make sure to close the form properly after you've finished using it.

**Another option might be to decouple the data you need to retrieve from Form1 from the form itself.**

Answer (score 0):

In this case, form 1 cannot be destroyed until form2 is also closed.  As long as form2 has a reference to form1, form1 will continue to exist.  More likely, you are concerned with form1 being disposed.  When form1 is closed, it will dispose itself.  The object will still exist, but it will have released all its child controls and system objects such as window handles and drawing objects.  Once a form has been disposed, it cannot be shown again, and all of it's controls will be inaccessible.  If you try to use any of the visual components of a disposed form, it will throw an `ObjectDisposedException`.  If you want to stop the form from being disposed, simply hide it rather than closing it.  However, you should close it later once Form2 no longer needs it, otherwise it will stay around eating up memory and resources.

Answer (score 0):

You should really factor whatever data you need out of both forms altogether, thereby avoiding the problem of coupled form constructors in the first place.